# A simple way to show my hostname/ip in Gnome Panel or on my Desktop Background?

Tags: widget, panel, gnome

Hi was searching for a while how i can add an app or widget that show me a output from a script or a command like "hostname --fqdn" on my Gnome Panel or on my Desktop Background...  conky does that, but i think that is to much for a simple shell output giplet does that only for ip and only for gnome panel and has no packages for debian wheezy.

i've many displays around 2000 in a bigger area and a running application, but if this application goes down the normal desktop is on top :) so in this case it would be nice to show a hostname/ip adress for engineering.

Answer (score 1):

You could work this out with a GNOME Shell extension.

I wrote a simple extension that will probably help you out on that.

The *extension.js* file:

```
const Clutter = imports.gi.Clutter;
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;

const COMMAND = "hostname --fqdn";
const FONT_SIZE = 48;
let stage_bg_color = Clutter.Color.get_static(Clutter.StaticColor.CHOCOLATE_DARK);

let myactor = null;

function run_command() {
    let output = "";
    try {
        output = GLib.spawn_command_line_sync(COMMAND, null, null, null, null);
    } catch(e) {
        throw e;
    }

    return output[1] + "";
}

function init() {
    let myactor = new Clutter.Text();
    myactor.set_font_name("Sans " + FONT_SIZE);
    myactor.set_position(400, 400);
    myactor.set_background_color(stage_bg_color);

    myactor.set_text(run_command());

    let n_children = Main.layoutManager._backgroundGroup.get_n_children();
    Main.layoutManager._backgroundGroup.insert_child_at_index(myactor, n_children);
}

function enable() {
}

function disable() {
}
```

The *metadata.js* file (watch out the shell-version):

```
{"shell-version": ["3.14.4"], "uuid": "cmd_wallpaper@felipeborges.net", "name": "Command wallpaper", "description": "It shows the output of a command on the wallpaper"}
```

Save both files in a folder inside *$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*. To enable it, use *gnome-shell-extension-prefs*

Or you could just download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hihetr6x7mzynqx/cmd_wallpaper%40felipeborges.net.zip?dl=0).

Comment: As of now, this answer works for Ubuntu 22.04 .   The name of the folder in the extensions directory must be the same as the "uuid" in the metadata.js file: "cmd_wallpaper@felipeborges.net".  Use "gnome-shell --version" to get the current "shell-version".  In Ubuntu 22.04 this is "42.0" .  This value must be added to the "shell-version" array in metadata.js .

Comment: As of GNOME Shell 45 (used in Ubuntu 23.10) this no longer works.